# Bundler could not find compatible version for gem "mimemagic"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install paperclip gem but when i command 'bundle install'
"Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic""
this line appears.

i have already tried to install it manually or by specifying its version.

Comment: There's some incompatibility between gem versions required by `paperclip` and your app (or other gems it depends on). 1. Have you tried `bundle update`? 2. (If `bundle update` doesn't help) The question cannot be answered as is - if you hope to have someone solve the problem for you, please post complete contents of your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Yes! i tried 'bundle update' 
same error appears a 'bundle install'

Comment: Since the reported conflict is in the `mimemagic` gem, inspect your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, find which gems depend on `mimemagic`, and try to find versions of the gems in question which have mutually compatible requirements on `mimemagic` version.

Comment: Thanks a lot its resolved.
The problem was of version incompatibility